# Determine which of two ImageMagick .TXT images is more saturated

Tags: code-golf, image-processing

You have two images (64x64 pixels each):

[image: saturated picture] [image: desaturated picture]

Your program must take the file names of each of them as command line arguments and determine which has more average saturation among their pixels.

The images are in ImageMagick .txt format.  You can download and convert these images using `convert pic.png pic.txt` or download the raw text ([saturated](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=5f3B4uxP), [desaturated](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VdjDm9HK))

Ignore the first line of the file (required).

Solutions in Assembly get 50% of their characters for free.  Brainfuck, whitespace, and close variants, get 25% of their characters for free.  (e.g. if it takes 200 characters in Brainfuck; mark it as 200-50=150.)

Describe your output.  It could be the name of the more saturated image; the index of it (0 for first, 1 for second); true for the first, false for the second, etc.  Just let us know.

It should be able to take either the saturated or desaturated image first, and accurately report the more saturated (test both ways).  The filenames shouldn't be considered when evaluating saturation (e.g. no `if filename contains 'desaturated'...`)

Shortest answer wins.  Happy coding :-)

Comment: What a hideous-looking input file format. Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: @PeterTaylor, indeed!  [.txt image documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#txt)

Comment: @beary605, you can join the two files together if that makes it easier :-)

Comment: How many of the 52 possible colour spaces must be supported? What bit depths must be supported? How should (partially) transparent pixels be treated for the purposes of averaging?

Comment: How will you know that the saturation values are correctly computed?

Comment: Of course its possible in Brainfuck. Except the bit about filenames and reading them.

Comment: -1 for scoring languages unequally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### J (<s>96</s> <s>94</s> 92)

```
echo/:(+/@:(m%(m=.>./)-<./)"1@:>@:(".&.>)@:((': (\(.*?\))';,1)&rxall)@:(1!:1)@:<)&.>2}.ARGV
```

Takes input from the command line as .txt files. It can take any number of files, and outputs a list of indices from saturated to unsaturated, i.e.:

```
$ jconsole saturated.j saturated.txt desaturated.txt
0 1
$ jconsole saturated.j desaturated.txt saturated.txt 
1 0
```

I've simplified the normal formula a bit: it does not bother to normalize the RGB values to [0..1], it uses the sum of the saturation per pixel rather than the average, and it actually calculates the inverse of the saturation and then sorts up. As long as the images are the same size (which they are), this does not affect the sort order which is what it's about.

Explanation:

- `2}.ARGV`: the command line minus its first two elements
- `&.>`: for each of these, do:
- `(1!:1)@:<`: read file
- `((': (\(.*?\))';,1)&rxall)`: use a regex to match the pixel values
- `(".&.>)`: execute each match as J code. `(1,2,3)` becomes the list `1 2 3` so now we have the pixel values.
- `>`: make a matrix from the list of lists
- `"1`: operate on the rows of the matrix
- `(m%(m=.>./)-<./)`: `MAX / (MAX - MIN)`, the inverse of the saturation
- `+/`: sum
- `/:`: sort up, so that the images are sorted in `S^(-1)` ascending, which gives the same order as `S` descending.
- `echo`: output the list

Comment: Impressive!  Nice explanation, too.

Answer (score 6):

### bash etc. and Image Magick (136 chars)

```
for x in "$@";do convert "$x" -colorspace HSL -channel G -separate -scale 1x1 t.txt
echo `sed "1d;s%.*#\(..\).*%\1%" t.txt` $x;done|sort
```

The way I see it, the easiest way to deal with the complexities of the Image Magick file format is to let Image Magick do it. `t.txt` seems to be the shortest possible filename which guarantees the correct output file format. The first 4 `"` could arguably be removed, but that would decrease robustness in the face of filenames with spaces in.

Sample output:

```
$ ./cmpsat.sh img-sat.txt img-desat.txt rose:
24 img-desat.txt
69 rose:
FE img-sat.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica  <strike>92</strike> 215

**Edit**

To work directly with the Magick files I had to make substantial revisions to my first try.

---

**Filenames**

Stored as variables, *x*, *y*.

```
x = "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=5f3B4uxP";
y = "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VdjDm9HK";
```

---

The following routine sorts image files by average saturation (least to greatest). (Spaces added for readability.)

```
i = Image; d = DigitCharacter;
f[t_] := {Mean[Flatten[ImageData[ColorConvert[i[i[Partition[(StringCases[URLFetch[t], 
   "rgb(" ~~ a : d .. ~~ "," ~~ b : d .. ~~ "," ~~c : d .. ~~ ")" :> ToExpression 
   /@ {a, b, c}])/255., 64]]], "RGB" -> "HSB"]], 1][[All, 2]]], t}
```

**Usage**

```
Sort@{f[x], f[y]}
```

**Output** (saturation value, followed by filename).

> {{0.229977, "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VdjDm9HK"},
>   {0.958346, "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=5f3B4uxP"}}

---

**Explanation**

`URLFetch[x]` fetches the Magick textfile, the name of which is stored in `x`

`StringCases[URLFetch[t], 
       "rgb(" ~~ a : d .. ~~ "," ~~ b : d .. ~~ "," ~~c : d .. ~~ ")" :> ToExpression 
       /@ {a, b, c}])/255., 64]]], "RGB" -> "HSB"]` finds the RGB values and, along with `Partition` converts them to the format Mathematica expects to find RGB files in.

`ColorConvert` converts to `Hue-Saturation-Brightness` values.
`Mean` and `[[All,2]]` find the mean saturation values for the file.

Comment: I think the OP is asking to get the input as a `*.txt` file (in ImageMagik format) and not in png format. it isn't very clear, though

Comment: here in 79 chars `f={a,b};Sort[{Mean@Mean[ImageData@ColorConvert[Import@#,"HSB"]][[;;,2]],#}&/@f]`

Comment: I was wondering about the formatting issue myself.  As for your code, I'm puzzled why the double use of Mean, but I'll look more closely.

Comment: Mean@Mean is equivalent to Mean@Flatten[...,1] but shorter

Comment: Not a real solution, because it doesn't use the .txt files (as @belisarius said), but cool nonetheless.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand This version uses the .txt files.

Answer (score 0):

### Brainf**k, 117 - 25% = 87.75

Requires an interpreter with 8-bit wrapping cells (this is the most common type).

```
>+[,<++++[->--------<]>[>+<]++++[->++++++++<]>]>>
>+[,<++++[->--------<]>[>+<]++++[->++++++++<]>]>
[-<<<[-]>>>]<<<[.]
```

Just input the text render of the first image and the second image. Make sure the files end with the `NUL` character (ASCII value 0). If the first image is larger, it will output how much larger it is than the second one (in the ASCII value). If the second image is larger, nothing will be printed.